# Как установить Java EE SDK для Eclipse?

Tags: java, sdk

Проблема в том, что я, похоже, очень сильно туплю, и в Eclipse мне не доступны javax.* пакеты, которые, как я понял, доступны в Java EE SDK, но на официальном сайте они предлагают сборку с GlassFish, которую я, хоть убей, не понимаю, как поставить.

Где можно найти нормальную версию или как установить предлагаемую на сайте Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> в Eclipse мне не доступны javax.* пакеты

Вот инструкция, которая поможет Вам настроить Eclipse.
[Установка необходимых инструментов: Java SDK и Eclipse Java](http://www.technerium.ru/java_studing/6-ustanovka-neobxodimyx-instrumentov-java-sdk-i-eclipse-java.html)

Скачать SDK: [Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
Выбираете нужную версию, качаете и устанавливаете.