# Как настроить J2EE?

Tags: java, j2ee

Сейчас у меня установлена версия `J2SE`. В виду начала изучения Java Enterprise хотелось поставить ЕЕ, но зайдя на сайт Оракл несколько потерялась.

Вопрос - откуда теперь ставить J2EE(jdk)?

Comment: JEE это набор спецификаций, нет конкретной реализации, кое что можно найти как эталонную реализацию, кое что имеет несколько реализаций. Не ко всему причастен Oracle. Поэтому надо сначала понять что вы изучать собираетесь...

Comment: Так как я учусь, думаю будет правильно ответить списком из краткой программы курса:

1. Java 8 Features
2. Advanced multi-threading
3. Build management
4. Logging frameworks
5. REST web services
6. Spring Core
7. Advanced unit-testing
8. Hibernate
9. JPA
10. Spring Data
11. Google Guice
12. Application Servers

Comment: Ну, поставьте IntelliJ Idea

Comment: у меня уже стоит eclipce - идея как то не понравился (стоял уже раньше)

как к нему прикрутить ЕЕ? что делать с glassfish с сайта Оракл и что это вообще такое?

Comment: @Ra'Uko вот здесь уже есть решение вашей проблемы: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/402462/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-java-ee-sdk-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-eclipse)